# Wix Howto determine if a directory exists during installation?

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3

Is their any chance in WiX to determine if a certain directory exits when the installer is running? I guess i have to use some sort of custom action, unfortunately i don't know how!  Furthermore i want to store the result of the custom action in a property and use this as an condition for calling another custom action. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like a DirectorySearch is what you're looking for. That will find a directory and assign the value to a Property.